# converting a URL to an HTML code

Tags: c#, html, url, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there any way to get whole HTML code of a URL? 
I saw some online convertes for PDF but I was wondering if I could convert it to HTML.
I can take an HTML code and use it as I please but I wanted to try and do the same thing using a URL.

Comment: *httrack* can solve your requirement.

Comment: @Manmohan_singh can I use it in my code?

Comment: Why not just use httpclient?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are asking. An URL does not necessarily reference an html page. So for example what would be the "HTML code" of an image file?

Comment: @Fildor I'm asking about URLs that reference to an HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get into code, Use `Selenium webdriver API`. It will launch a driver instance by which you can launch a **URL** and extract **page source** as well. For more info visit [selenium HQ](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). A python code snippet to scrape web page would look like below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.seleniumhq.org')

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

print soup.find_all("td", class_="td1_normal_class")
```